# My database won't connect

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm not sure why my db isn't connecting. I'm basically trying to produce a website in javascript, and I'm using an AJAX to call a method in a php file. This method is a query so I can get results of this query into some of my js components. Can anyone help please? I've been stuck for ages! Any help is appreciated.

Part of my javascript file:

```
function callPHP() {
    $.ajax ({

        type: "GET",
        datatype: "application/json",
        url: "BaseClass.php",
        data: { action : 'getResults()' },
        //error: function(err){console.log(err)},
        success: function(output) {

            console.log(output);

        }
        //error, function(err){console.log(err)}
    });


}

callPHP();
```

My BaseClass(The content in the comments wouldn't work):

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    require("Conn.php");
    require("MySQLDao.php");

    $param=$_REQUEST['action'];

    /*
    $handle = fopen("php://input", "rb");
    $raw_post_data = '';
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $raw_post_data .= fread($handle, 8192);
    }
    fclose($handle);
    */

    if (empty($param))
    {
        $returnValue["status"] = false;
        $returnValue["title"] = "Error";
        $returnValue["message"] = "No Data Recieved paige" .$param ."...";
        echo json_encode($returnValue);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        $dao = new MySQLDao();
        if ($dao->openConnection() == false)
        {
            $returnValue["status"] = false;
            $returnValue["title"] = "Error";
            $returnValue["message"] = "Connection Could Not Be Established Between Server And Database";
            echo json_encode($returnValue);
        }
        else
        {
            //Decodes data, dont change
            $body = json_decode($raw_post_data, true);
            $recieved = $body["data"];

            //Gets the result of a query
            //$result = $dao->MySQLDaoMethodName(parameters);

            //Return the result of the query
            echo json_encode($result);
        }
        $dao->closeConnection();
        return;
    }
?>
```

My conn.php:

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    class Conn
    {
        public static $dbhost = "***";
        public static $dbname = "***";
        public static $dbuser = "***";
        public static $dbpass = "***";
    }
?>
```

MySQLDao.php(this file holds the methods I wish to call from my js file):

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    //Class for holding queries
    class MySQLDao
    {
        var $dbhost = null;
        var $dbuser = null;
        var $dbpass = null;
        var $mysqli = null;
        var $dbname = null;
        var $result = null;


        //constructor
        function __construct()
        {
            $this->dbhost = Conn::$dbhost;
            $this->dbuser = Conn::$dbuser;
            $this->dbpass = Conn::$dbpass;
            $this->dbname = Conn::$dbname;
        }

        //Attempt a connection to the database
        public function openConnection()
        {   

            //Try and connect to the database
            $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $this->dbname);
            //If the connection threw an error, report it
            if (mysqli_connect_errno())
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        //Get method for retrieving the database conection
        public function getConnection()
        {
            return $this->mysqli;
        }

        //Close the connection to the database
        public function closeConnection()
        {
            //If there is a connection to the database then close it
            if ($this->mysqli != null)
                $this->mysqli->close();
        }

        //-----------------------------------QUERY METHODS-------------------------------------

        public function getResults($data)
        {

            $sql = "SELECT room.room_description FROM room WHERE room.room_id = 1";

            $result = $this->mysqli->query($sql);


            //if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            //  $obj = mysql_fetch_object($result, 'obResults');

            //}

            echo json_encode($result);

            echo($result);

        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: Why are dbhost, dbuser, dbpass, etc. all set to null? Did you just replace them to make sure you don't give any confidential info here, or are they missing in your actual code?

Comment: Just for confidential reasons yea

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Where is this failing? Does the AJAX request return a 404, 500, something else?

Comment: And if you put on your browser something like `http://localhost/yourprojectfolder/BaseClass.php?action='getResults'`

Comment: It's showing {"status":false,"title":"Error","message":"No Data Recieved paige..."}. this is cos $param is empty but I have no idea why

Comment: And I tried this Hackerman but still getting the same error

Comment: Then `var_dump` out the contents of `$_REQUEST`. If doing the test in the browser with `...?action=foo` you should definitely see the value passed in. Not seeing any MVC framework or anything right? Just pondering if 'action' was a "reserved" word perhaps. Don't think that is it though.

Comment: Perhaps you should create a debug log in your PHP code and output what the code is doing. Here is a [super simple logger](https://gist.github.com/ryantxr/fb2b2fa9fa63b34a1bd9) you can use to debug.

Comment: The var_dump is just null

Comment: Take a look at php error log in your server

Comment: Try: `var_dump($_GET);` and see if you get anything then.

Comment: var_dump($_GET); shows array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: Really should check logs. Probably an error telling you what is going on. Other thing to try... change variable name to something other than 'action' if you then see the value in the dump take a look at `variables_order` EGPCS (Environment, Get, Post, Cookie, and Server) with an eye open for possible collisions.

Comment: If you change data: { action : 'getResults()' }, to data: { action : 'getResults' }, - i.e. no round brackets does that help?